# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' string comparison

Tags: string, algorithm, c++11, stderr

Compose the largest number out of a set of integers. The set of integers can be more than 1 digit.

Since the numbers can be more than one digit, using greedy algorithm and sorting them in descending order wont help.
Eg: Input : 21 and 2 ,
 Sorting in descending would give an answer 212 which is wrong since the 221 > 212

I decided to come up with the following algorithm:
I have a vector of strings as input so I use the std::sort function with a custom function to sort it.

If I have two strings i = "21" and j ="2", I concatenate i,j and j,i and then compare the result

```
bool isGreater(string i,string j){
  string a = i+j;
  string b = j+i;
  return a >= b;

}

string largest_number(vector<string> a) {
 string result =" ";
 sort (a.begin(),a.end(),isGreater);
 for(int i =0; i<a.size(); i++){
   result+=a[i];
 }
  return result;
}
```

It works for some cases but I fail a few test cases and get the message:

stderr:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your comparator is wrong. It should meet *strick weak ordering* rules [described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).  `isGreater("2","2")` returns true, but it should return false to fulfill `sort` comparator requirements. Change to `return a > b;` in place of `return a >= b;`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! I pass all the test cases now but I am not quite sure why using >= gave me and error. If I have ("22","2"), it doesn't matter how I arrange it since the answer is always 222.

Comment: `sort` modifies elements of input range depending on comparator result. Because your predicate was incorrect, some elements of input vector might have been modified (copied or moved), but they should have been not affected, that is why `sort` crashed.